# Why isn't this multivibrator working?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, oscillator

I've built a simple multivibrator circuit and PCB but I get no oscillation whatsoever. I am expecting an oscillation on pin 3 of each transistor but get 0V on TR2 and 12V on TR1.

Can anyone suggest why this is? I have simulated the exact circuit in LTspice and it works as expected.

[image: Circuit]
[image: Top Layer]
[image: Bottom Layer]

Answer (score 1):

First : Sure of wiring ?

It seems that one base TR1 is grounded ? (lower picture) ?

Then ... R1, R3 may be a little high ... Choose between 10k & 20k ...

Another reason of "not working" is the "symmetry" of such design.

Try inserting a little resistor between 1 emitter and ground (100 Ohm ?).

Comment: +1 for the perfect simmetry issue, probably is getting metastable. I'd try 'tickling' one base to ground to see if it starts after that

Comment: It only looks as if one base is grounded. With a transistor on each side, one is flipped vertically wrt the other.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is component placement. You've taken advantage of symmetry and placed, for instance, R1 and R3 at the same location but on opposite sides of the board. Same with C1 and C2, and R2 and R4. Same with the transistors.

When you installed your components, R3, R4, C1 and TR2 are unlabeled. If, for instance, you installed the others first, then flipped the board vertically to install these, you need to install C1 BELOW R3, not above it as you did with C2/R4. This is not true if you flipped the board horizontally.

This is all a good indication why you should probably start out with all components on the same side of the pcb. That way you can label every component, rather than having to wing it.